# Can we create a file using stored procedure - Oracle Server is UNIX based and the file should be created in Windows Server

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

For a specific requirement we need to create a file from the Oracle procedure.
I understand that we can create a file using procedure in Oracle.But our Oracle Server is Unix based and i want to create the file in our windows server.
Is it possible to run the Oracle procedure which will create the file and place it in Windows Server?

Comment: Yes, create a mount on the Unix server of a folder in the windows server...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I found one more command "spool" which also creates the file in the windows server. spool '\\servername\path\filename'